# Generalized Ulam spirals, can we do better than four?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, integers

I am not a mathematician, but I know most infinite sets have the same cardinality, meaning they contain the same number of elements, because the elements can be mapped one to one.

This is true for even numbers, odd numbers, prime numbers, composite numbers, natural numbers, Fibonacci numbers, integers and rationals... The first six series are easy to demonstrate, start with index equal to 0, you can assign a unique index for each number in the series, you just increment the index by 1 every time you assigned an index. (But the real numbers have a bigger cardinality than integers.)

This is easy to demonstrate:

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b


for i, n in enumerate(fib(10)):
    print(i, n)
```

```
0 0
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 5
6 8
7 13
8 21
9 34
```

But what about integers? Integers go in two directions, so you can't just increment the index to enumerate the numbers. To include negative integers in this way, we need a lowest number, and increment from there. The problem is, no matter how small the number is, there would always be numbers smaller than that, and because the series grows in one direction, we can never reach the smaller numbers... And we can't just start with negative infinity, since obviously negative infinity plus any finite number is negative infinity.

This can be solved by getting zero first, then for each positive number, we first get its negative, then itself:

```
from itertools import islice

def integers():
    yield 0
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield -i
        yield i
        i += 1

for i, n in enumerate(islice(integers(), 10)):
    print(i, n)
```

```
0 0
1 -1
2 1
3 -2
4 2
5 -3
6 3
7 -4
8 4
9 -5
```

But what about rationals? Rationals have two components, they have two dimensions, surely they have a bigger cardinality than the natural numbers?

Well, I have seen the a variation of the following graph be used to prove the rationals have the same cardinality as the natural numbers, and it also proves the cardinality of lattice points is the same as integers:

[image]

The graph is constructed using the following instructions:

```
start with x = y = 0, and length = 1
yield x, y
do the following endlessly:
    increment length and x
    yield x, y for length iterations, in each iteration decrement x and increment y, until x = 0
    increment length and y
    yield x, y for length iterations, in each iteration decrement y and increment x, until y = 0
```

But I don't like it, in the graph, the x coordinate and y coordinate overall increase and not decrease. Because when one coordinate increases the other can either decrease or stay the same, and there is a lower limit to the coordinates. And the coordinates are only in the first quadrant.

So I created another graph that is like a spiral:

[image]

As you can clearly see, the coordinates both increase and decrease, and the graph spans all four quadrants. The graph is composed of segments and right angles, at every point only one coordinate changes and the other stays the same, and every two turns the spacing between the turns increases by one.

But I don't like it, because I can't include negative integers in it.

So I created another graph, which contains a pair of spirals like the first one, one is a rotated copy of the other, both cross half the lattices, and they don't intersect with each other, and the lengths of the segments increase by two every two turns:

[image]

But I thought I can do better, there are four true neighbors for each lattice, the spirals can go in four directions, so I created yet another graph that contains four rotated copies of a spiral like the first one, each crosses a quarter of the lattices, the spirals don't intersect and the segments increase their length by two every turn. This creates two number polylines so I used pure imaginary integers as another series of indices:

[image]

But I am still not satisfied, because every lattice has eight neighbors, and I tried very hard to create a series of 8 spirals that all are of the same shape, don't intersect with each other, and each cross an eighth of the lattices, so they together cross all lattices in two dimensional space, but I can't.

First off, four of the starting segments would have a length of $\sqrt{2}$ and four others with length 1, they won't have the same shape, and if they stay straight rays they will never cross all lattices, and every way I tried to turn them they end up eventually intersect with each other.

Is there a formal mathematical proof that there can never be a set of eight such spirals that have the same shape and don't intersect and cross all lattices?

What about sixteen? I cannot imagine sixteen such spirals, but there are no three dimensional numbers, however there are quaternions.

What about three dimensions? Can there be such set of spirals that all have the same shape, don't intersect each other, and together cross all (x, y, z) points where x, y, z are integers? If so, what is the maximum number of spirals such a set can have?

I know Hilbert curve and Peano curve have 3D generalizations, but I don't have very good spatial imagination. By the way, you can read my code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jxn4x7DfyKopLOhvPgrmn0HZOx92rRAG/view?usp=sharing).

---

My question is simple, given recursive Cartesian product of a set, like so:

$$product(\mathbb{A}, 0) = \mathbb{A} \\
product(\mathbb{A}, n) = product(\mathbb{A}, n - 1) \times \mathbb{A}$$

For example, $product((0, 1), 2)$ is the following:

```
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1)]
```

The set of lattice points in $n$ dimensions is $product(\mathbb{Z}, n - 1)$, denote the set with $\mathbb{S}$, $\mathbb{S}$ is also countably infinite.

Create a series of sets, in such a way that every set in the series contains an element from the multi product (or can be used as a coordinate in $n$ dimensional space), all sets contain unique elements and every element from $\mathbb{S}$ appears exactly once in the series of sets eventually, and each set corresponds to a one-dimensional polyline embedded in $n$ dimensional space, and the polylines are a spiral-like, and the spirals can be aligned through rotation and/or reflection.

Is the maximum number of sets a series like I have described in two dimensional space four? Can there be such a series of sets in three dimensional space? If so, then what is the maximum number of sets such a series can have?

Comment: Not only the set of rational numbers, even the set of algebraic numbers is still countable. However, it is not trivial to enumerate them in such a way that each number eventually occurs in the (infinite) list. But I think this is not the main question.